# Add incremental zero padding to filenames

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm running into an issue where I have a directory of files names:

```
something1.exr
something2.exr
something3.exr
```

and I need them named like

```
projectname.0000001.exr
projectname.0000002.exr
projectname.0000003.exr
```

I've come up with this:

```
NAME=image_test_GAM_4778x1806 c=1; for i in *.exr; do mv "$i" `printf $NAME."$c".exr`; let c=c+1; done
```

and it is able to rename files like:

```
image_test_GAM_4778x1806.1.exr
image_test_GAM_4778x1806.2.exr
image_test_GAM_4778x1806.3.exr
```

However, I need the incremented number to have 7-digit padded zeros so I found I can do that with `"%07d"`, therefore I assume this code should work:

```
NAME=image_test_GAM_4778x1806 c=1; 
for i in *.exr; do 
    mv $i $(printf “%s.%07d.exr” “$NAME” “$c”); 
    let c=c+1; 
done
```

But it doesn't work and complains I'm using mv incorrectly. I know theres something wrong but logically it should make work, I'm trying to pass $NAME and $c to “%s.%07d.exr” respectively.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You have curly quotes in the second block of code.

Comment: don't use uppercase variable names, that's conventionally reserved for environment variables

Comment: Fix the quoting and your second loop works.

Answer (score 0):

Using [rename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) utility with a perl expression:

```
rename -n "s/something(\d+)(.*)/'projectname.' . sprintf('%07d', \$1) . \$2/ge" *.exr
```

Using **-n** flag is useful to test until you found the exact expression:

```
something10.exr renamed as projectname.0000010.exr
something1.exr renamed as projectname.0000001.exr
something2.exr renamed as projectname.0000002.exr
something3.exr renamed as projectname.0000003.exr
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s suggestion in the comments - this was an issue with curly quotes.

I changed the quotes to regular parallel quotes and it works.